# Want to make a Jukebox that plays a soundcloud url given by website users

Tags: javascript, web, soundcloud

I am making a website for educational and fun purposes.
Now I want to make a 'Jukebox', 'Radio', 'Music player', call it whatever you like. 
But basically I want to have a textbox or something where I can put a soundcloud url and then the song will play in the background and everyone on the site can hear it.

Can someone help me with it because I dont know where to start.

Comment: something like this site has in the header https://csgospeed.com/home

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you'll have to do id register a an app with soundcloud on their developers site [here](https://developers.soundcloud.com/) and once you have the app registered you should be able to consult the Http guide and reference to embed a player that takes a user given url, works with javascript/python/ruby.

Comment: Okey, I got a working example I think but I want that the song I play is playing for everyone on the site, for now only I hear the song

Comment: Well this just a suggestion, you'll have to do some research to find out if this best and I'll upload some sample code when I get home, but you could just embed the selected track with hyml5 audio tag and play it from there.

Comment: Well the problem is that only I will hear the sound, and not the users on my website

Comment: Have you tried and can you post the code sample in an edit, if you can set the source of the audio tag to the url given by the user it should play for all users of site